# Android Studio - Modding Firefox search suggestions error - "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited"

Tags: android, firefox

[image]

I'm modifying the Firefox Android App. I'm trying to change the search suggestions feature from Google to another search engine. To do this I have to change 2 files

The first file I change is:

```
fenix/app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/search/list.json
```

The second file that I add is:

```
app/build/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/out/searchplugins/test.xml
```

After I make these changes and run the app in the emulator to test it out, the changes that I make are reversed/undone/overwritten, and the notice pops up saying "Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited".

What should I do to make my changes save here? Why are the files being reverted back to before I changed them?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Why are the files being reverted back to before I changed them?` because the alert tells you why ? they are generated files

Comment: Ok. How can I find out how they're generated?